# Access SVG element via jquery or javascript in ie6,7,8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, svg

I have issue regarding to ie6,7,8. I know that these versions does not support SVG.

My problem is I have svg code and rendered in hidden div so which is not used for displaing. now I want to manipulate attribute of tags of SVG like defs, rect etc.

I have googled a lot but could not find any valuable information.

Comment: perhaps you can try to handle the svg as xml document which is not inserted into the dom

Comment: You could ask the user to install an SVG Viewer plugin such as [Adobe SVG Viewer](http://download.cnet.com/Adobe-SVG-Viewer/3000-2356_4-11240.html). Many of these include functions and utilities which could help and would also allow you to display in older browsers (should you wish). Point of note - Adobe SVG Viewer is no longer supported by Adobe, however, I think there may be others out there. Maybe not the best solution, but perhaps you could share more on what your aims are? If you only want to manipulate SVG then I would definitely consider the above suggestion, so +1.